# odoo many2one as selection field

Tags: python, odoo

I'm creating a module  in odoo and i wanna  use a many2one as a selection field, the problem is on the name of the city 'ville en francais' the dropdown works and it saves the id of the city(from database) but the name is like obj.ville,1 (it shows the name of the module,id instead of the name of the city in database)

[image: table output]

[image]

```js
class obj_ghotel(osv.osv):
 _name = "obj.ghotel"
 _description = "Objet ghotel"
 
    def _get_selection(self, cr, uid, context = None):
        ville_obj = self.pool.get('obj.ville')
    ville_obj = self.env['obj.ville']
    res = []
    ville_ids = ville_obj.search(cr, uid, [], context = context)
    for g in ville_obj.browse(cr, uid, ville_ids, context = context):
        res.append((g.id, g.nom_ville))
    return res
    _columns = {
  'nom_hotel': fields.char( "Nom d'hotel", required=True ),
        'adr_hotel': fields.char( "Addresse hotel", required=True ),
        'id_ville':fields.many2one('obj.ville','ville', selection=_get_selection), #fields.integer('Id Ville', required=True ), #Foreign key references ville(id)  'id_ville':fields.many2one('ville','ville'),
        'image': fields.binary( "Image" ),
 }
```

```js
class obj_ville(osv.osv):
    _name = "obj.ville"
    _description = "Objet ville"


    _columns = {
        'nom_ville': fields.char( "Nom Ville", required=True ),
        'id_hotel':fields.one2many('obj.ghotel','id_ville'),
    }


    _defaults = {
        'Nom Ville': "Name",
    }
```

Comment: Use `name` field in `obj.ville` model  or use `_rec_name` to the specify the name (`_rec_name = 'field_name'`) of the record.

Comment: could you please show us the source code for obj.ville

Comment: @kerbrose i edited the post with the source code of obj.ville

Comment: @Zety i'm already using 'name ' field i edited the post.

Comment: @skizzgp Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_rec_name` as following:

**Hotel** model:

```
class obj_ghotel(osv.osv):
    _name = "obj.ghotel"
    _description = "Objet ghotel"
    _rec_name = 'nom_hotel'
```

**Ville** model:

```
class obj_ville(osv.osv):
    _name = "obj.ville"
    _description = "Objet ville"
    _rec_name = 'nom_ville'
```

Comment: Fixed Thnx Man +rep @Zety

Comment: I am glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

you need to define a method called name_get like the following

```py
def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]
    res = []
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        name = record.nom_ville
        res.append((record.id, name))
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is when odoo don't know how to represent the record, he show you by default the name of the model and the id of the record.

How odoo know how to represent the record, this is don in `name_get` method defined in `models.py` first he looks for the value of `_rec_name` by default is name some i'm assuming that you don't have a field name in the model `obj.ville`, je pense que t'as ulilisé `nom` ^^.

so you need to change the `_rec_name`:

```py
 class Ville(models.Model):
    _name = 'obj.ville'
    _rec_name = 'nom'
```

Comment: i'm already using _name = 'obj.ville' you can see the source code i updated the post :) .

Comment: Oh thnx you and @Zety helped me thnx guys + rep

Answer (score 0):

Many2one fields are by default kind of selection fields.
At first you create a model for ville with 'name' as an attribute

```
class OdooVillePerso(models.Model):
    _name = 'odoo.ville.perso'

    name = fields.Char('Ville')

class OdooFinalClass(models.Model):
    _name='odoo.final.class'

    ...

    ville = fields.Many2one('odoo.ville.perso', 'Ville')
```

After that you can just call it in another model as a Many2one and it will appear as selection field but  don't forget to creata a view for the model.

**PS: This code works on odoo 10**

Comment: You haven't do that. I have told you to name the variable **name** instead of **nom_ville**

Answer (score 0):

Better you can add options in XML  no_open & no_edit.